# Java Regular Expression math test

Tags: java, regex

I have a text that is

```
page=2&items=200
page=3&items=400
page=4&items=600
..
```

Clearly, there exists a math equation here where:

```
items = ( page - 1 ) * 200
```

And I am wondering will regular expression be able to detect that?

```
page=\d+&items=($1-1)*200? (pyseudo)
```

So any lines that don't match that math equation will fail?

```
page=3&items=400 (success)
page=3&items=450 (fail)
```

Thanks!

Comment: java regex expression doesn't do any calculation.

Comment: those are not regular expressions.  & is a bitwise and operation.  The result of the first page=2... is the value 0 (0x02 & 0xC8 = 0x00).

Comment: Use the regex to match the pieces and then write a function to test.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* - jwz

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that is such a great quote.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch One might argue that, in this case, there is only one problem: PIBKAC ;-)

Comment: A regular expression is not able to do this: one needs at least a context-free grammar I think...

Comment: @CommuSoft Don't confuse parsing with semantic checks. The grammar for this little thing can be handled with a regex, it's regular, Chomsky type 3.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't check if a number in front of a string is equivalent with a number at the end of the string (or worse, do some arithmetics on it). Only if the bits are interleaved this is possible. The question was if a regex is capable to detect this. The answer is *no*. But indeed, as you point out, you can parse data and then check it (with a Turing machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This - although not just a regex - does the check. Numbers should be "sane" or an Exception is thrown.

```
private static Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "page=(\\d+)&items=(\\d+)" );
private static boolean check( String s ){
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( s );
return mat.matches() &&
    (Integer.valueOf( mat.group(1) ) - 1)*200 ==
    Integer.valueOf( mat.group(2) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer laune, you can replace mat.matches() with mat.find() if you dont' want to "match the entire region against the pattern" (i.e. page=xx&items=xx is only part of the text)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String sampleString = "page=2&items=200";
    String [] splitArray = sampleString.split("page=|\\&items=");

    System.out.println(sampleString.matches("page=\\d+\\&items=\\d+")); 
    System.out.println((Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1]) - 1) * 200 == Integer.parseInt(splitArray[2]));
```

You will have to write 2 conditions, one to check the format (check the first SOP) and then do the maths (check the second SOP)